# Architecture for communication with sensor network

Tags: c, architecture, raspberry-pi

I have several raspberry pis, each one connected to a sensor module. I have written a C program which runs on each raspberry pi to communicate with the sensor module and to configure it properly (the driver for the sensor module is written in C).
The next step is to make the configuration of the sensor modules more flexible and to enable other applications to communicate with the sensor modules over the network.

To make the configuration more flexible I thought about creating a web application which is able to connect to the raspberry pis (all of them are in the same wifi) and configure the sensor modules remotely.

My idea is to create a REST Api which runs on each raspberry pi and enables the communication with the sensor module. But as my application is written in C, I was wondering if there is any better solution to my problem? I know that creating a REST Api in C is possible, but, as far as I know, it is not very common.

Would you think that creating a REST Api in C for this use case is a good idea and if so, is there any good framework available?

Also, if someone has a better idea for a different architecture, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here over the network means tcp/ip? REST API in c is common, you can pick libraries that suits your needs. AFAIK I used REST API in client/server model makes more sense. REST API you need to have JSON schemes to serialise/deserialse the data.

Comment: Have you looked into MQTT broker for your work?

Comment: Thank you for your answers! 
@LethalProgrammer sorry I forgot to mention, in my system I mean tcp/ip with network. As I am not that experienced with C, is there any specific library I should definitely take a look at?

Comment: @Nitro I haven't considered it yet, but I am not sure if a messaging middleware is the right way to go as I need the communication mainly for configuration purpose.